# Выводит постоянно null

Tags: c#, mongodb

Вот мой метод в `Repository`:

```
public virtual Task<TDocument> FindOneAsync(Expression<Func<TDocument, bool>> filterExpression)
{
      return Task.Run(() => _collection.Find(filterExpression).FirstOrDefaultAsync());
}
```

тут у меня постоянно выводить `null`:

```
var dash = await dashRep.FindOneAsync(x => x.ChartsPage == cp.Id);
```

а если сделать так, (но тут мы загружаем *10000* записей в ОЗУ - это плохо)

```
var dashBoards = dashRep.AsQueryable().ToArray();
var dn1 = dashBoards.Where(x => x.ChartsPage == cp.Id).SingleOrDefault();
```

то выводит нормальный объект, помогите пожалуйста, что не так?
Вот моя сущность:

```
[BsonCollection("DashboardsNew")]
    public class Dashboard : Document
    {
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public ObjectId ChartsPage { get; set; }

        public string Icon { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
        public string Tag { get; set; }
        public string[] Groups { get; set; }
        public decimal Value { get; set; }
        public Translate Description { get; set; }
        public Translate Measure { get; set; }
        public Rate[] Rate { get; set; }
        public bool IsFavourite { get; set; }
        public bool ShowOnMain { get; set; }
        public bool IsDefault { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }
    }
```

шаблон репозитория:

```
public class MongoRepository<TDocument> : IMongoRepository<TDocument>
        where TDocument : IDocument
    {
        private readonly IMongoCollection<TDocument> _collection;

        public MongoRepository(MongoProvider provider)
        {
            _collection = provider.db.GetCollection<TDocument>(GetCollectionName(typeof(TDocument)));
        }

        protected string GetCollectionName(Type documentType)
        {
            return ((BsonCollectionAttribute) documentType.GetCustomAttributes(
                    typeof(BsonCollectionAttribute),
                    true)
                .FirstOrDefault())?.CollectionName;
        }

        public virtual IQueryable<TDocument> AsQueryable()
        {
            return _collection.AsQueryable();
        }

        public virtual IEnumerable<TDocument> FilterBy(
            Expression<Func<TDocument, bool>> filterExpression)
        {
            return _collection.Find(filterExpression).ToEnumerable();
        }

        public virtual IEnumerable<TProjected> FilterBy<TProjected>(
            Expression<Func<TDocument, bool>> filterExpression,
            Expression<Func<TDocument, TProjected>> projectionExpression)
        {
            return _collection.Find(filterExpression).Project(projectionExpression).ToEnumerable();
        }

        public virtual TDocument FindOne(Expression<Func<TDocument, bool>> filterExpression)
        {
            return _collection.Find(filterExpression).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        public virtual Task<TDocument> FindOneAsync(Expression<Func<TDocument, bool>> filterExpression)
        {
            return Task.Run(() => _collection.Find(filterExpression).FirstOrDefaultAsync());
        }

        public virtual TDocument FindById(string id)
        {
            var filter = Builders<TDocument>.Filter.Eq(doc => doc.Id.ToString(), id);
            return _collection.Find(filter).SingleOrDefault();
        }

        public virtual Task<TDocument> FindByIdAsync(string id)
        {
            return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var filter = Builders<TDocument>.Filter.Eq(doc => doc.Id.ToString(), id);
                return _collection.Find(filter).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
            });
        }


        public virtual void InsertOne(TDocument document)
        {
            _collection.InsertOne(document);
        }

        public virtual Task InsertOneAsync(TDocument document)
        {
            return Task.Run(() => _collection.InsertOneAsync(document));
        }

        public void InsertMany(ICollection<TDocument> documents)
        {
            _collection.InsertMany(documents);
        }


        public virtual async Task InsertManyAsync(ICollection<TDocument> documents)
        {
            await _collection.InsertManyAsync(documents);
        }

        public void ReplaceOne(TDocument document)
        {
            var filter = Builders<TDocument>.Filter.Eq(doc => doc.Id, document.Id);
            _collection.FindOneAndReplace(filter, document);
        }

        public virtual async Task ReplaceOneAsync(TDocument document)
        {
            var filter = Builders<TDocument>.Filter.Eq(doc => doc.Id, document.Id);
            await _collection.FindOneAndReplaceAsync(filter, document);
        }

        public void DeleteOne(Expression<Func<TDocument, bool>> filterExpression)
        {
            _collection.FindOneAndDelete(filterExpression);
        }

        public Task DeleteOneAsync(Expression<Func<TDocument, bool>> filterExpression)
        {
            return Task.Run(() => _collection.FindOneAndDeleteAsync(filterExpression));
        }

        public void DeleteById(string id)
        {
            var filter = Builders<TDocument>.Filter.Eq(doc => doc.Id.ToString(), id);
            _collection.FindOneAndDelete(filter);
        }

        public Task DeleteByIdAsync(string id)
        {
            return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var filter = Builders<TDocument>.Filter.Eq(doc => doc.Id.ToString(), id);
                _collection.FindOneAndDeleteAsync(filter);
            });
        }

        public void DeleteMany(Expression<Func<TDocument, bool>> filterExpression)
        {
            _collection.DeleteMany(filterExpression);
        }

        public Task DeleteManyAsync(Expression<Func<TDocument, bool>> filterExpression)
        {
            return Task.Run(() => _collection.DeleteManyAsync(filterExpression));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Зачем здесь `Task.Run`? Если так попробовать: `public virtual Task<TDocument> FindOneAsync(Expression<Func<TDocument, bool>> filterExpression) { return _collection.Find(filterExpression).FirstOrDefaultAsync(); }`

Comment: Что такое `_collection`?

Comment: @aepot так тоже пробывал, не получается

Comment: А если вместо `.FirstOrDefaultAsync()` использовать `.SingleAsync()`?

Comment: @aepot зачем? он и так ничего не находит

Comment: Ну тогда вам виднее. Для начала избавьтесь от всех `Task.Run`. И почитайте это - [Асинхронное программирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async).

Comment: @aepot даже так ничего не выводит var dn =  dashRep.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.ChartsPage == cp.Id).FirstOrDefault();